# A linear function that maps the unit sphere to the unit sphere is continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

Let $X, Y$ be normed vector spaces and $T:X\rightarrow Y$ linear. Let $S_X, S_Y$ be the unit spheres of $X, Y$ respectively. E.g. $S_X=\{x \in X:||x||_X<1\}$

If $TS_X = S_Y$, then $T$ is surjective, continuous and $||T||=1$.

I can see the surjectivity, but cannot figure out the continuity, from which I'm sure the norm of $T$ follows. Hint please.

Comment: Doesn't it follow from the definition of $\|T\|= \sup \{ \|Tx\| \colon x \in S_X \}$?

Comment: Does it make sense to think of $\| T \|$ before proving $T$ is continuous thought$?$ You didn't prove it is continuous (yet).

Answer (score 0):

Let $T: X \to Y $ linear with  $X$ and $Y$ normed vector spaces and $TS_X=S_Y$

Consider $B_\epsilon(y_0) = \{y \in Y | |y-y_0|_Y < \epsilon \}$
for $y_0 \in Y$, $x_0 \in X$ $ f(x_0)=y_0$

Then $T^{-1}(B_\epsilon(y_0)) = \{ x \in X | |T(x)-T(x_0)|_Y < \epsilon \}$

$= \{ x \in X | |T(x-x_0)|_Y < \epsilon \} $

$= \{ x \in X | |T(\frac{x-x_0}{|x-x_0|_X})|_Y*|x-x_0|_X < \epsilon \}$

$= \{ x \in X | |x-x_0|_X < \epsilon\}$ $=B_\epsilon(x_0)$ using $TS_X=S_Y$

Thereby T is continous

Comment: Why is $|T(\frac{x-x_0}{|x-x_0|_X})|_Y=1$?

Comment: This is because $\frac{x-x_0}{|x-x_0|} \in S_X$ and therefor it is mapped to $S_Y$ by definition of T

Comment: Look again at my question, it's $<1$ not $\leq 1$

Comment: Ahh sorry I just read unit sphere which usually is defined as $S_X = \{x \in X| |x|_X = 1\}$

Comment: But then you can just replace $|x-x_0|$ by $|x-x_0|*1.1$ so you know it is in $S_X $ and then you dont get the epsilon ball but one for a delta different to epsilon, but this doesn't matter for continuity, or you just use the result from your answer that $|T| = 1$

Answer (score 0):

Assume there is an $x\in S_X$ s.t. $||Tx||_Y>||x||_X$. Then consider $y:=\frac{x}{||Tx||_Y}$. Then $||y||_X<1$ but $||Ty||_Y=1$, a contradiction to $TS_X=S_Y$. Hence $T$ is bounded. $||T||= 1$ follows from Evangelopoulos F.'s comment.